# Failed assertion: line 541 pos 14: 'constraints.biggest.isFinite': is not true

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have below source code in my app, I add this animation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfHcP.gif this animation suggest in my another topic: [Button and text field flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105318/button-and-text-field-flutter)

But some phones gives me error when I use this animation when I press other text, seems like it goes on forever. And I found this error when this happened, how can I solve this ?

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 541 pos 14: 'constraints.biggest.isFinite': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AnimatedSwitcher AnimatedSwitcher:file:///Users/duygu/StudioProjects/qr_code_payment/lib/screens/PaymentCard/card_information.dart:208:23
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:541:14)
#3      RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:597:12)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#5      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#6      RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:570:43)
#7      RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:597:12)
#8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#9      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#10     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#11     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#13     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:233:12)
#14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#17     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#18     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1005:7)
#19     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#20     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403:14)
#21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#25     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1376:11)
#26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#31     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:437:14)
#32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#33     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#34     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1005:7)
#35     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#36     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403:14)
#37     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1731:7)
#38     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
#39     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:497:19)
#40     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#41     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#42     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#43     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#44     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#48     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#49     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#50     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 5 frames from class _AssertionError and dart:async)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderStack#d3656 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(411.4, 70.0)
...  alignment: Alignment.center
...  textDirection: ltr
...  fit: loose
RenderObject: RenderStack#d3656 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(411.4, 70.0)
  alignment: Alignment.center
  textDirection: ltr
  fit: loose
```

And related part of source code:

```
         child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: animationDurationInMs,
                    child: _textFieldHasFocus
                        ? null
                        : Center(
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedBalance = 50.0;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: itemsSize,
                                    height: itemsSize,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Color(0xff6a81f9),
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    ),
                                    child: const Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        '50',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 32,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedBalance = 100.0;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: itemsSize,
                                    height: itemsSize,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Color(0xff6a81f9),
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    ),
                                    child: const Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        '100',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 32,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedBalance = 150.0;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: itemsSize,
                                    height: itemsSize,
                                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Color(0xff6a81f9),
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    ),
                                    child: const Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        '150',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 32,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: itemsSize,
                                  height: itemsSize,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
                      final spaceBetween =
                          (constraints.biggest.width - 4 * itemsSize) / 5;
                      return Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: animationDurationInMs,
                            width: _textFieldHasFocus
                                ? constraints.biggest.width -
                                    2 * spaceBetween
                                : itemsSize,
                            height: itemsSize,
                            child: Center(
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: TextField(
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedBalance =
                                          double.tryParse(value)!;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  focusNode: _focusNode,
                                  maxLines: 10,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: 'Other',
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(16)))),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: spaceBetween,
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFF6A81F9),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFF6A81F9), width: 1)),
                child: Text(
                  "Charge : " + selectedBalance.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
           ...
```

Comment: Can simplify the widget that will reproduce the same error , More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I reduce the source code @YeasinSheikh I added only related widget part. But I coulndt reduce error maybe somebody help with error details

Comment: Can I remove `CreditCardWidget`?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Stack` with SizedBox and provide height. Also you can wrap with `Expanded` to get available height.

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: itemsSize, //this one
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      AnimatedSwitcher(
```